# Spring getBean() of prototype with constructor parameters throws error

Tags: java, spring

I am facing an issue of getting a prototype bean with some runtime constructor parameters from spring context. It throws this error when I call `context.getBean()` method:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.getBean(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

My AppConfig is like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public QueryAction getQueryAction(IoSession session, Message message) {
        return new QueryAction(session, message); 
    }

}
```

and my code to get the bean is like below:

```
ContextProvider.getContext().getBean(QueryAction.class, session, message);
```

I'm pretty sure the parameters`(session and message)` that I am passing in are of correct types. Can anybody please help with this?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @hotzst I'm using 4.1.6 for all core, beans, context and context-support

Comment: @ShawnSong this looks like you are using different spring version in compiling time and runtime.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera I got this error even when I debugging my program in eclipse.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> This is just my half-arsed solution. I can only put it as an answer because of the word limit.

Alright, here is what I have done so far.

I have just setup a clean project with one main function and with only spring dependencies. No problem at all! In eclipse, I then checked the `Java Build Path -> Order and Export` tab of my previous project. I found spring jars are at bottom. As I have dependencies on other jars and projects so for testing purposes, I simply moved all spring jars up to right under my source folders. Then the problem is resolved.

I believe the issue is caused by some of the spring classes are not loaded because  my other dependencies have exactly the same package name and class name. The solution on top of my head is to use a different ClassLoader to load and instantiate spring's `applicationContext` but I'm not sure whether that's feasible or not.

I will come back to this question later.